# Lasso feature selection Nature of features and model to use

Tags: regression

i am going to use Lasso regression for feature selction and i have a mixture between discrete, continuous and categorical values. Do i have to fit the model with Logistic regression or it can be handled and what about the feature should them be normalized ????

```
'data.frame':   173 obs. of  72 variables:
 $ Diagnosis                           : int  2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ INDICATION                          : int  2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.loading.dose            : int  4 4 6 4 6 4 4 4 4 6 ...
 $ Time.of.collection..Hours.          : int  1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.maintenance.dose        : int  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.carboxylic.acid..ng.ml. : num  1740 740 2060 9310 7720 2110 7760 5140 6400 528 ...
 $ Clopidogrel..pg.ml.                 : num  9010 99.5 597 848 652 473 6800 808 973 453 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.acyl.glucuronide..ng.ml.: num  2610 235 6840 7620 19000 1310 9090 1970 26200 6840 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.active.metabolite       : num  0 0 930 3471 0 ...
 $ CYP2C19.2                           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ CYP2C19.17                          : int  2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ CYP2C9.2..rs1799853.                : int  2 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ CYP2C9.3..rs1057910.                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Number.of.dilated.artery            : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Type.of.artery.1                    : int  1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 ...
 $ Number.of.stents.Artery1            : int  2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Clopidogrel.treatment.duration      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Coronarography.results              : int  2 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ Event.time                          : int  2 0 1 0 1 3 1 6 0 0 ...
 $ Event                               : int  1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age                                 : int  1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sexe                                : int  2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Obesity                             : int  4 4 3 2 4 4 1 4 2 2 ...
 $ Hypertension                        : int  1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Diabetes                            : int  1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Non.insulinodependant.diabetes      : int  1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Insulin.dependent.diabetes          : int  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Smoking                             : int  2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Dyslipidemia                        : int  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ HyperCT                             : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ HyperTG                             : int  1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Mixed.dyslipidemia                  : int  2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Family.history.of.CAD               : int  2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Renal.failure                       : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Previous.MI                         : int  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ Previous.PCI                        : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Previous.CABG                       : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ Previous.stroke                     : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ Alcohol                             : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Systolic.blood.pressure             : num  140 110 110 120 140 140 110 120 130 120 ...
 $ Dyastolic.blood.pressure            : num  80 70 70 70 80 80 60 80 80 80 ...
 $ Glycemia                            : num  12 5 8 7 7 13 6 6 6 7 ...
 $ Creatinine                          : num  180 90 104 76 121 92 100 120 400 800 ...
 $ Urea                                : num  11 5 9 3.5 6 4.4 6 5.5 30 14 ...
 $ CPK                                 : num  65 214 6000 420 113 ...
 $ Triglyceride                        : num  2.99 1.25 1.7 1.2 1.49 3.94 0.61 1.05 1.33 4.89 ...
 $ Cholesterol.total                   : num  4.58 3.6 4.28 5.3 4.7 5.06 7.88 3.25 4.14 5.08 ...
 $ Na                                  : num  138 136 140 138 138 139 138 139 135 130 ...
 $ Cl                                  : num  106 104 103 102 102 102 100 104 100 100 ...
 $ K                                   : num  4.5 4 3.1 3.6 3.7 4 4 4.78 4.5 6 ...
 $ Leukocytes                          : num  8000 9450 15000 11600 15000 6000 10000 7600 10000 9000 ...
 $ Hemoglobin                          : num  12 14.5 12 12.1 10.7 11.2 14.8 14 11 13.1 ...
 $ Platelets                           : num  250000 230000 300000 379000 213000 219000 180000 148000 250000 213000 ...
 $ Statins                             : int  3 4 1 3 0 0 4 3 0 0 ...
 $ Dose.statins                        : num  20 10 10 20 20 20 10 20 20 20 ...
 $ Aspirin                             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ Aspirin.loading.dose                : num  250 250 250 250 250 250 250 100 250 250 ...
 $ AVK                                 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ACE.inhibitor                       : int  2 2 3 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 ...
 $ DOSE.IEC                            : num  75 37.5 2.5 25 37.5 75 37.5 25 37.5 37.5 ...
 $ Angiotensin.II.receptor.antagonist  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Beta.blockers                       : int  1 4 4 1 0 0 0 6 4 0 ...
 $ DOSE.BB                             : num  25 2.5 1.25 25 25 25 25 200 1.25 25 ...
 $ Calcium.channel.blocker             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Diuretic                            : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Diuretic.ARAII                      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Proton.pump.inhibitor               : int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ dose.ipp                            : num  40 40 40 40 80 40 40 40 40 40 ...
 $ Nitrated.derivatives                : int  1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ AGRASTAT                            : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Reopro                              : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Cardio1M                            : Factor w/ 2 levels "anomalous","normal": 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: You will need to say something about the nature of the outcome variable as that determines the type of regression to try.

Comment: i have added a description of the structure of the types of features used Should i convert them (for example int to factor for some of them) here to be more meaningful

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interested in time-to-event data, given the variables `Event` and `Event.time`. So the best approach would be to use survival analysis rather than logistic regression, as logistic-regression analysis would lose all the information about times to events. There are ways to apply LASSO, ridge regression, or elastic net with survival analysis, for example with the `glmnet` package in R.

In general, features should be normalized before applying such approaches, so that the different predictor variables are all on the same scales as far as possible. Otherwise results and the predictors selected might differ if your measurements are in, say, mol/liter instead of mg/liter units.

Your categorical variables are presently coded as integer values. You may need to make sure that the software interprets them correctly as categorical variables; how to do that depends on the software, e.g., use as.factor() in R. Otherwise they might be interpreted as continuous variables, a problem if there are more than 2 categories.